# @Transactional Spring chaining and self invoking

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-transactions

I want to know the potential side effects of chaining @Transactional method calls calling from a private method from the same class. From researching this seems to be a limitation from Spring and can cause side effects but what if the corresponding class calls as separate class that also has the @Transactional Annotation? If B fails, does B rollback and A?

```
@Service
public class A {
    @Autowired
    private B myB;

    @Transactional
    private void transactionA(){
        myB.transactionB();
    }

    public void doTransactionA() {
        transactionA();
    }
}

@Service
public class B {
    @Transactional
    private void transactionB(){
        //throw an exception
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all.

> When using proxies, you should apply the @Transactional annotation
>   only to methods with public visibility

So keep that in mind if you only want to run on the standard Java `Proxies`.
 Any other case is covered by `CGLIB`.

Anyway that depends. The `@Transactional` annotation supports transaction propagation.

- `PROPAGATION_REQUIRED`: a logical transaction scope is created for each method upon which the setting is applied. Basically each "nested" method call will join an existing transaction, if any.
- `PROPAGATION_REQUIRES_NEW`: uses a completely independent transaction for each affected transaction scope. Each annotated method has its own transaction.
- `PROPAGATION_NESTED`: uses a single physical transaction with multiple savepoints that it can roll back to. Basically if a nested call fails, only that one is rolled back, and execution continues.

For a better overview, see [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/data-access.html#transaction).